# Liquid Mapping/Xsd Schemas for CData

Tags: cdata, azure-logic-apps, liquid-xml

I'm fairly new to Azure logic apps as well as xml so bear with me:

I'm trying to change an XML file to JSON using logic apps, but my XML file contains CData. I think my schema file is correct but I don't know the correct way for liquid to map directly to the XML response data. Could anyone provide me with any extra info for parsing through this response data?

Comment: Provide information you have researched first before asking someone to do you `homework` for you.

Comment: Here's a hint to clear up something in the UI.  For Xml to Xml, you should be using Xslt.  Using the JSON base Liquid is not appropriate.  You can develop the xslt using a variety of tools.

Comment: To help clarify, I'm an intern working on a project for my company.. I have very minimal knowledge with XML/JSON, and even less knowledge with Azure. In looking for a way to convert XML to JSON using Azure, I went to logic apps. The only XML-JSON logic app that would work for that uses liquid mapping.

Comment: I don't need help with my "homework", just a better understanding of how liquid mapping works.

Comment: Hi Jordan, It would help if you could share a sample of your input message and how you want that to be transformed. E.g. what's inside the CDATA element?

Comment: I've learned that the CDATA won't effect mapping.
I have a post Xml request that when sent produces a response similar to this

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
      <Names>{
        "Units":[
{"First":"Jordan", "Last":"Taulton"},
{"First":"Bob", "Last":"Smith"},
{"First":"Jen", "Last":"Thomas"}
]}
      </Names>
    </User>
</soap:Envelope>

I'm wanting to map to the Names tag and transform that into JSON.